# How to do this summation: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log_{2^\frac{n}{2^n}}256$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, sequences-and-series

How to do this summation?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log_{2^\frac{n}{2^n}}256=?$$

All I'm getting is $8(2 + 2 + \frac83 + \frac{16}{4} + \cdots )$ which is a diverging series.

Comment: $$\log_{2^\frac{n}{2^n}}256=\frac{2^{n+3}}{n}$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A single term of series is $$\log_{2^{\frac{n}{2^n}}} 256=\frac{\log_2 256}{\log_2 2^{\frac{n}{2^n}}}=\frac{2^n8}{n}$$ First condition for series to be convergent is that it's terms should converge to $0$, but here $\frac{2^n8}{n}\to \infty$ as $n\to \infty \implies $ this series is not convergent.

Comment: So, am I correct?
This summation is not convergent, thus no finite answer?

Comment: you got it right. :)

Comment: It doesn't even have to be a base-2 logarithm, since $\log_b a=\dfrac{\log_c a}{\log_c b}$ for $c$ positive and $\neq 1$.

Comment: When n tends to infinity, (8)(2^n)/n is indeterminant, isn't it?
Its of the form inf/inf

Comment: $2^n$ grows much faster than $n$ when $n$ increases, thus $\frac{2^n}{n}$ diverges to $\infty$ (you can also apply L'Hopital's Rule) and for the base-2 part, you can choose whatever base you want(if it diverges for base-2, it will diverge for every other base.)

Answer (score 3):

You have 
$$\log_{2^{n/2^n}}(256) = {{\log(256)}\over {\log(2^{n/2^n})}}= {\log(256)\over n/2^n\log(2)} = {8\cdot 2^n\over n }$$
A series with these terms will diverge, since the terms themselves will become unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

Also without any transformation since we have

$$\frac{n}{2^n}\to 0^+\implies 2^\frac{n}{2^n}\to1^+$$

then $\log_{2^\frac{n}{2^n}}256$ diverges to $\infty$.